# How to execute shell command with performTaskWithPathArguments?

Tags: javascript, ios7, xcode5, instruments, ios-ui-automation

Why does the following command not work ?

```
UIATarget.localTarget().host().performTaskWithPathArguments("ANY TEXT", [">>", "ABSOLUT PATH"], 15);
```

This returns exitCode 0 and stdout looks fine: `ANY TEXT >> ABSOLUT PATH`.
If the output is copied into terminal it works fine.

I´ve a solution for it, in which I call a script like

```
UIATarget.localTarget().host().performTaskWithPathArguments("PATH TO SCRIPT", ["ANY TEXT"], 15);
```

In the Script is the simple Code:

```
echo $1 >> "ABSOLUT PATH"
```

But now I need to run only one command, because I can´t use any Scriptfiles…

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIATarget.localTarget().host().performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout(
"/bin/bash",
["-c", "/bin/echo ANY TEXT >> 'ABSOLUT PATH'"],
15);
```